# How to hide products in Shopify search results based on a vendor name

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm in a situation where hiding a certain vendors products in the control panel isn't an options due to an outside POS.  For a test in search.liquid, I used search.terms like below.  This code works but not everyone will type thevendor exactly the same way and will see the products if they don't type thevendor.

```
{% for item in search.results %}
{% if search.terms == 'thevendor' %}
{% else %}
{% include 'search-result' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to figure out how to write the code to hide these products in a better way.  I tried product.vendor like below but when I search for those products individually they are not hidden.  The code:

```
{% for item in search.results %}
{% if product.vendor == 'thevendor' %}
{% else %}
{% include 'search-result' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?  It seems it doesn't know what product.vendor is but when I print out who the vendor is, it displays the vendor.  I don't understand why it's not hiding the products that are associated with this vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for item in search.results %}
{% if item.product.vendor == 'thevendor' %}
{% else %}
{% include 'search-result' %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This should work.